# Tor Hidden Service in Plesk

Tags: nginx, hidden, plesk, tor

at first sorry for my bad english.

I am using Plesk 12 on my Ubuntu 14.04 Server. In the past i made Tor hidden services for my Domains simply whit the Apache virtual Host Files. And it Works fine.

But now i am using Plesk and now i dont understand hor to make a Exsiting Site reachable over a Hidden Service.

The Site www.example.com is available an the Host settings are :

```
 <VirtualHost 85.214.50.74:7080 >
    ServerName "example.com:80"
    ServerAlias "www.example.com"
    ServerAlias "ipv4.example.com"
    ServerAdmin "admin@example.com"

.....
```

Now i added a second Virtual host :

```
 <VirtualHost 85.214.50.74:8081 >
    ServerName "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.onion:80"
    ServerAlias "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.onion"
    ServerAdmin "admin@xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.onion"

......
```

In the Torrc the Hidden service ist Corret and it generated a kex and a hostname. But if i reload Apache and Nginx and restart Tor, i cant reach the Hidden service.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't add the onion site as a virtual host.  Apache doesn't serve the requests to the .onion site directly.

Instead, edit your `torrc` file and add something like:

```
HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/example.com
HiddenServicePort 8081 127.0.0.1:80
```

This runs a hidden service on port 8081 that proxies to port 80 on the local host.  When you first start Tor it will generate all the keys and the onion address for your site which you can find in `/var/lib/tor/example.com/hostname`

If you have multiple virtual hosts, you might need to change the `HiddenServicePort` to use the hostname (or serveralias), but make sure it resolves locally so you're proxying to the local machine.